# Trying to Retrieve data from Twilio Studio Flow Rest API?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am trying to send data from `Postman` to `Twilio studio Flow RestAPI`. The request has the basic authentication and set data in variables `Params`. The variables I am passing are `To, From, and body`. The image of the request is attached here to clarify what I am trying to request.

[image: PostMan Requeset is attached]

I had read the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#rest-api-trigger) and found that `flow.data.(any_variabe)` can access the data passed to the API but it's not working.

[image]

I am not clear what I am missing but assuming that the data as parameters are not passing from the request to twilio. Can you please guide me where I am doing wrong. The log flow is

[image]

I am a newbie to `Twilio Studio Flow Rest API`. If I had missed some information to inform you about the case please ask I will elaborate it further.

Comment: @philnash #philnash or Twilio Geek Please assist me about the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View the document [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007778153-Trigger-a-Twilio-Studio-Flow-Execution-via-the-REST-API).

```
curl -X POST https://studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Executions \
--data-urlencode "To=+13105555555" \
--data-urlencode "From=+12125551234" \
--data-urlencode "Parameters={\"patient\":\"Jon\",\"time\":\"8AM\"}" \
-u "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token"
```

[image]

Comment: I were missing the `Parameters` keyword. Thanks, you saved my day.